New Authentication Pattern for Android Applications and SFMCSdk Android version
During latest spring release SF announced some changes regarding Sending Services related to Android Sending. So basically we need upload Firebase Config File (Service Account JSON) for each Android app in our Marketing Cloud in order to stay compliant with requirements for Google Firebase Cloud Messaging. We do have one question though.
We also intend to update SFMCSdk Android from 8.0.6 to 8.1.5 but we did not intend to do that quite yet. Would uploading and using the Service Account JSON for an app which is on v8.0.6 cause any problems with sending push notifications? Would it be more suitable to wait for the update of the app with the latest SDK version and then implement/upload the Firebase Config File (Service Account JSON)?
I am sorry, I know it might be a weird question but mobile development and SF Marketing Cloud are something very new in my career.
Thank you in advance.

The JSON requirement is independent of any SDK updates.
